# How to add feature “don't copy when pressing command” in this c program—macPaste?

Tags: macos, keyboard, c++, c, objective-c

https://github.com/lodestone/macpaste

https://github.com/lodestone/macpaste/blob/master/macpaste.c

With this little  project, I can copy a text to clipboard with just select a text, in macOS.

This stuff saved my life, but  in some circumstance, it’s a bit complex

e.g.

```
aaa      bbbbbbb ccccccc

aaa      ddddddd ccccccc
```

There are two rows above, I want  to copy  `dddddd` , and replace `bbbbbb`   in row one:

```
(
   result may like this:

   aaa      ddddddd     ccccccc 
   aaa      ddddddd     ccccccc
)
```

The fast way is double click the word in row 2, and it will select dddddd(and copy with macPaste)

Then i want to double click ddddd, and press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, but when I select ddddd,

the word is copy to clipboard,

how to add a feature in this code, when I pressing <kbd>command</kbd> key, macpaste will not copy selected text

Comment: Are you asking how you can add a feature to a program you are writing? What have you tried?

Comment: Its not i write   ,i tried to read code and edit, i think this feature may not very hard  but i can't did it ...